# How to work with SQL Server LocalDB in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, sqlite, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin, I would like to use SQLServer LocalDB for my new projects. However, Xamarin suggests to use SQLite (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/) ... is it possible at all to use SQLServer LocalDB in crossplatform apps? if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLServer LocalDB is not supported on Android or iOS.